# Replace contents of lxml StringElement with starting a namespace war?

Tags: python, lxml, kml

I can't figure out how to replace contents of lxml StringElement (styleUrl in this case) which already has a namespace (other than pytype). I end up getting an element level namespace injected. This is a much distilled and simplified version that only tries to rename one StyleMap to illustrate the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from pykml import parser as kmlparser
from lxml import objectify

frm = "lineStyle30218901714341461519022"
to = "s1"

b4_et = kmlparser.parse('b4.kml')
b4_root = b4_et

el = b4_root.xpath('//*[@id="%s"]' % frm)[0]
el.attrib['id'] = to

el = b4_root.xpath('//*[text()="#%s"]' % frm)[0]
el.xpath('./..')[0].styleUrl = '#'+to

objectify.deannotate(b4_root, xsi_nil=True)
b4_et.write(sys.stdout, pretty_print=True)
```

test data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>Wasatch Trails</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Style id="lineStyle30218901714341461519049">
        <LineStyle><color>ff0080ff</color><width>4</width></LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="lineStyle30218901714341461519027">
        <LineStyle><color>ff0080ff</color><width>4</width></LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="lineStyle30218901714341461519022">
        <Pair><key>normal</key><styleUrl>#lineStyle30218901714341461519049</styleUrl></Pair>
        <Pair><key>highlight</key><styleUrl>#lineStyle30218901714341461519027</styleUrl></Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Placemark>
        <name>Trail</name>
        <styleUrl>#lineStyle30218901714341461519022</styleUrl>
        <LineString>
            <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            <coordinates>
                -111.6472637672589,40.4810633294269,0 -111.650415221546,40.48116138407261,0 -111.6504410181637,40.48118694372887,0
            </coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

The only issue I have not been able to resolve is lxml putting a **`xmlns:py="http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify/pytype"`** attribute into the newly created styleUrl element. I'm guessing this is caused by the document having a default namespace for kml/2.2. I don't know how to tell it the new styleUrl should be kml instead of pytype.

```
...
<styleUrl xmlns:py="http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify/pytype">#s1</styleUrl>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing following:

```
el.xpath('./..')[0].styleUrl = '#'+to
```

with:

```
el.xpath('./..')[0].styleUrl = objectify.StringElement('#' + to)
```

will give you what you want. But I'm not sure whether this is the best way.

BTW, you can use `set(key, value)` method to set attribute value:

```
el.set('id', to)  # isntead of  el.attrib['id'] = to
```

Comment: The solution is much more simple than I expected, I wonder why the assignment doesn't do this under the covers in the first place. I assume there is some __magic__ method that implements (can override) the assignment behavior. How does the pytype namespace even get involved? I read the lxml docs a few times and failed to really grok the objectify thing.

Comment: @Mike, According to [`lxml.objectify` documentation](http://lxml.de/objectify.html): `objectify.E` is an instance of objectify.ElementMaker. By default, it creates pytype annotated Elements without a namespace. You can switch off the pytype annotation by passing False to the annotate keyword argument of the constructor.

Comment: @Mike, So, `M = objectify.ElementMaker(annotate=False); el.xpath('./..')[0].styleUrl = M.xyz('#' + to)` can be another solution. (seems like, the mehtod name `xyz` does not matter unless the call enclose another call like: `M.xyz(M.xyz('123'))`)